# Homebrew precompiled binaries for macOS 10.15 Catalina. When they will be available?

Tags: macos, homebrew, catalina

When will the Homebrew precompiled binaries for macOS 10.15 Catalina be available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Homebrew waits until Catalina’s official public release.

> as all bottled builds are generated only for supported macOS versions

https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-do-you-compile-everything

Comment: This is true, however, I'd like to add a note that even as of today (Catalina public beta), you can get precompiled binaries that _work_ on Catalina. They're just the Mojave builds, it seems, in my experience. Just in case the OP was wondering if they would have to compile everything from source if they tried to use `brew` in Catalina today. There is, however, a note that it is officially unsupported.

Comment: That’s exactly what I want. I don’t want to compile everything from source on Catalina.

Comment: Catalina has been released now, are they available now?

Comment: And now I'm wishing they continue to be available but I guess I'll have to make do without them.